# What are the map scales related to mapquest's zoomlevels?

Tags: android, osmdroid, mapquest

In my Android project im using mapquest data with OSMdroid. I would like to know what map scales the zoomlevels provide (e.g. 1:10000 etc.). I just found [zoomlevel to scale depending on DPI](http://www.mapquestapi.com/staticmap/zoomToScale.html) (Is the map's scale also depending on the width and height of the map view, that I am showing?). If I use [the mapquest map site](http://www.mapquest.de/#b2adcf4ea68c617acbb1dbf4), I just see a mapscale in the bottom left corner, but not in a ratio like 1:10000, which I actually need.

What are the scales 1:x at zoomlevel 16,15,14 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few things going on here. Let me step through it as I understand it.

First, I believe what you are seeing in the Mapquest link is the ratio. So for zoomlevel 16,15,14:

14 = 1:27083
15 = 1:13541
16 = 1:6770

Although the link doesn't specify it, that should be in meters. So in zoom level 14, every pixel represents 27083 meters.

Additionally, the Bing maps ratios are found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb259689.aspx). They are pretty close to the numbers that Mapquest reports, but they are not the same.

So, why are the numbers different? Because the meters-per-pixel ratio changes depending on what latitude you are at. Because of the distortion the Mercator projection produces, the meters-per-pixel is not constant as you change latitude. The Bing maps values are the values at the equator. I don't know where the Mapquest values come from.

Finally - to calculate meters-per-pixel in osmdroid you can call:

```
TileSystem.GroundResolution(latitude, zoomLevel);
```

And that will give you meters-per-pixel for a specific latitude. I recommend you take a look at osmdroid's `ScaleBarOverlay` for an example of how to apply this information.

Comment: i did not have in mind that the mercators projection changes the scale depending on the latitude value.

Answer (score 0):

Stay at the 0° latitude or the equatorial line (earth radius of 6372.7982km for the earth model of the map and equatorial circunference approximate as 40041.472km):

- zoom level 0 represents 360° in a window (of 256px) which is on the equatorial line 40'041km
- zoom 1 only 180° in the same window which is 20020km
- zoom 2 is  90°, or 10010km
- and so on always halving.

The scale (always speaking at the equatorial line) depends on the size of your window, if it is 1km wide, it is:

- zoom 0 is 1:40041
- zoom 1 is 1:20020
- zoom x is 1:40041/2^x
- etc

If the window is 1 inch wide:

- zoom 0 is 1in:40041km or 1:1'576'417'322
- zoom 10 is 1in:40041/1024km or 1:1'539'470
- zoom 16 is 1:24054

If the window is 200px wide (for a 180 DPI screen):

- zoom 0 is 200px:40041km or 1:1'418'775'590
- zoom 18 is 200px:40041km/2^18 or 1:5412

This is just on the equatoriali line (0° latitude). In the north or south there is a correction factor to be applied, which is cos(latitude degrees).

Comment: thanks, but the answer by kurtzmarc was more helpful for me as an developer (and it was more proper in time as well)